# Adjective: attributive "leftover", predicative "left over"

Tags: adjectives, orthography, past-participles

Wiktionary's entry for [left over](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/left_over) reads:

> Use *left over* after a verb, in a predicate phrase. When directly
> before a noun, use *leftover*.

Is this a general productive pattern? Otherwise, any reference for this usage note?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more common and productive pattern is for an open spelling in predicative position to correspond to a hyphenated spelling in attributive position: *These shoes are worn out* vs. *worn-out shoes.*

Alternatively, some writers may use the open spelling in both positions: "worn out shoes".

The use of closed spellings is not very predictable; it can be a matter of convention and might depend on the extent to which the specific construct has come to be thought of as a single unit/word.

The prevalence of the closed spelling *leftover* might be related to the use of *leftovers* or *(the/a) leftover* as a noun. Hyphenated *left-over* is an alternative for the noun as well as the attributive adjectival construct.

I can't think of another set of spellings for a participial construct with the exact same distribution as *left over, left-over* and *leftover.* *Rundown* exists as a closed spelling, but it seems to be found fairly frequently in predicative position.

*Far away, far-away* and *faraway* are not participial, but I think these spellings may show a similar distribution: *far away* dominates in predicative position (where "faraway" would look odd to me), but *faraway* can be found in attributive position, with hyphenated *far-away* as a variant to the closed spelling.<sup>1</sup>

---

1. [Grammarist Quick Entries: F](https://grammarist.com/quick-entries/f/)